# generating svg with c2

Tags: clojure, svg, clojurescript

I have the following code, meant to represent a set of devices as SVG:

```
(ns foo.core
  (:use [c2.core :only [unify]]
        [c2.dom :only [replace! append!]]
        [c2.svg :only [translate]]))

(def conf 
  { :devices [{:alias "OSC Sender",
               :name "OSC Sender",
               :ins []},
              {:alias "const2", :name "const",
               :outs []}],
    :layout [{:alias "const2",
              :x 72.12447405329594,
              :y 99.88499298737729},
             {:alias "tick",
              :x 82.5732819074334,
              :y 133.91374474053296},
             {:alias "OSC Sender",
              :x 185.17741935483872,
              :y 113.90322580645162}]})

(def render-config
  [:svg {:viewBox "0 0 900 400"}
   [:rect {:id "frame" :x "1" :y "1" :width "600" :height "300" :fill "none" :stroke "blue"}]
   (unify (:layout conf)
          (fn [{alias :alias x :x y :y}]
            [:g {:transform (translate [x y])}
              [:text alias]]))])

(append! "#main" render-config)
```

Trying to evaluate `render-config` in the REPL, I get:

```
[:svg {:viewBox "0 0 900 400"} [:rect {:width "600", :y "1", :x "1", :fill "none", :stroke "blue", :id "frame", :height "300"}] ([:g {:transform "translate(72,99)"} [:text "const2"]] [:g {:transform "translate(82,133)"} [:text "tick"]] [:g {:transform "translate(185,113)"} [:text "OSC Sender"]])]
```

which looks like a proper Hiccup representation to me (certainly `unify` did its magic).

Yet when evaluating `render-config` in the context of a web page (using `singult`), I only get an error. Generating a very simple SVG (basically only the enclosing "frame" rectangle) works in the browser.

Any hints/tips?

Cheers!

*Note: rendering `render-config` using `Hiccup`, then spitting out the results in a file gives a SVG image that is readable by Inkscape.*

Comment: `TypeError: b is undefined`. Note that this is from the compiled javascript, so does not give much hints (one of the main clojurescript issues IMHO).

Comment: isn't the `unify` code should be inside :rect ie. `[:rect ... (unify ..)]`

Comment: @Ankur: Apparently not: rendering using `Hiccup`, then spitting out the results in a file results in a SVG image that is readable by inkscape...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `unify` is not an only child.
In ClojureScript unify has the semantics of "make sure all of the children here are these data through this template fn", and what's happening is that Singult is trying to turn the `rect` into a `g` (to match the template).
This is nonsensical, which is why it's blowing up.
If you wrap the unify so it looks like

```
[:g.devices (unify ...)]
```

you should be fine.

This works on the serverside because there `unify` is treated as if were `map`.